# What function was last called in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a script and I want to enable logging of errors. The first thing I want to log is where the script was called from? I.e. In which part of my code did the error occur and maybe even a list of how it got to the point where it broke? What functions were called etc?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [debug_backtrace](http://jp.php.net/debug_backtrace) to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.php.net/debug_backtrace.